# Launch & restore session of safari from application in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, session, safari

My use case is such that I want to launch my app from safari and back to SAME SESSION of safari from my application.
Step 1:

- Launch my app from safari browser [Able to achieve it successfully]

Step 2:

- Launch safari by maintaing the same session from where the app was launched [In step 1]

How to achieve Step 2?

the code below is to launch safari

```
NSString *strurl = @"http://www.google.com"
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithtring:strurl];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

NOTE: the code above will launch the safari for the specified URL.

**- How do I launch the safari by restoring the previous session?**

- Is there any possibility of safari sending me the unique ID of the page when I launch an app from it so that when I try to launch safari back from my app, it would be useful.[Just a vague idea].

Answer (score 0):

I think there is definitely a way to accomplish what you are looking for here. Since you say that you have successfully achieved Step 1, it sounds like you have registered a custom URL scheme for your application, and set up a URL in Safari which the user clicks on to open your application. Let’s pretend your custom URL scheme is `myApp://` in which case all you would need to do is embed whatever information your application needs to know about where to send Safari as part of that URL, something like `myapp://mysite.com/page/to/display`

Then, in your app delegate’s `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method, you can look at the URL that was used to open your application, and store away the part you need to tell Safari to return to, `mysite.com/page/to/display` in this example. (If you are using a version of iOS older than 4.2, then the simpler method `application:handleOpenURL:` will be called instead.)

So let’s assume that in this method we store the URL we were given in a property `openedURL` as follows (this code goes in your application delegate):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    self.openedURL = openURL;
}
```

Then when you want to relaunch Safari, just use the saved information to open Safari to the right place. You need to swap out the `myApp:` scheme with `http:` so that it gets sent to Safari:

```
NSURL *safariURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithScheme:@"http"
                                            host:[openedURL host]
                                            path:[openedURL path]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[safariURL autorelease]];
```

If the URL you are opening needs to send other information to your application, which seems likely, then you need to do something a bit more complex, but you can still embed the page you want to go back to in Safari as a query parameter in the URL or something like that: `myApp://process?arg1=foo,arg2=bar,safariContext=mysite.com/page/to/display` (with proper URL encoding, of course).

Does that make sense?